# is there any possible way to just resume the app where it left in Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

guys i am working ionic app development, I have created the app and deployed in the mobile and whenever i minimize the app and again resume it, it starts from the beginning i.e from the splash screen and home page again. is there any possible way to just resume the app where it left?e
Any Suggestions?
Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to manipulate the generated AndroidManifest.xml file

```
          android:launchMode=["standard" | "singleTop" | "singleTask" | "singleInstance"]
```

Try to add this to the Config.xml file:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
</platform>
```

Comment: Try <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />